# Error 404 while creating simple new controller file in magento module

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

I have running project. and I have just added new controller file but whenever I am trying to call that from my URL its showing 404 error when I am writing another controller name its showing correctly. I am not getting where is problem

**config.xml**

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <CustomerMobile>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Customer_CustomerMobile</module>
           <frontName>CustomerMobile</frontName>
        </args>
     </CustomerMobile>
  </routers>
```

Controller file **ProductreviewController.php**

```
class Customer_CustomerMobile_ProductreviewController extends 

Customer_CustomerMobile_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo $this->__("working test");
    }
}
```

url i am trying is `http:/localhost/CustomerMobile/Productreview`

Comment: you have not defined any layout for your controller action so it is redirecting to 404

Comment: but i have to write function like after giving review on product the function will proceed then how i can write a layout for this.

Comment: after echo in action put `die();` and check if your action is called, if yes then you can proceed with you function. Also in your `config.xml`  change `routerNode Alias` and `frontName` to lowercase

Comment: i tried die(); but its not its not getting the controller action only how i can write layout file just to check for controller working or not

Comment: if your `die('something');` is not working, your layout won't work too, your Url must be forwarded to a proper controller action to make it work.

Comment: is your module enabled and displaying in admin under module list?

Comment: all other controller files are working. if i change only name of controller its echo the data and when i change name of controller to my name then its not showing i have not created layout file

Comment: in this case you should check for typo in controller filename, class and url

Comment: have you tried url http:/localhost/index.php/CustomerMobile/Productreview ?

Comment: yes vivek i tried that. Can you tell the procedure.. i wanted to create my controller in existing module and want to check whether its working. then how i can do that

Comment: @user64090, please check my answer.

Comment: Please post your whole config.xml (or at least the whole frontend node) - based on what you say ("... when I am writing another controller name ...") I'm pretty sure you have defined multiple routers in this config where the frontnames are conflicting with each other and probably only the latest one will be taken into account since it's not set up correctly...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have extended to the wrong class:

**class Customer_CustomerMobile_ProductreviewController extends 
Customer_CustomerMobile_Controller_Action**

should be

**class Customer_CustomerMobile_ProductreviewController extends 
Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action**

Comment: I checked this but still its not happening anything its showing 404 error . is there anything else we have to do if you want to create any new controller file